# AngularJS: Creating a $http service

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm a little new to Angular, and I'm trying to set up a very simple RPC implementation that uses angulars `$http` service (factory) to do the work. Here's what I have for the service so far:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('xxx')
  .factory('rpcService', function ($http) {

    return {
      request: function(method, params, callback) {
        var service = method.split('.');
        params = params || {};
        params.method = service[1];
        return $http.post('/services/' + service[0] + '.sjs', params).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
      }
    }

  });
```

Then when I want to use the service, I call it like the following:

```
rpcService.request('Users.facebookLogin', { token: response.authResponse.accessToken })
  .then(function(response) {
    debugger;
    $rootScope.user = response.user;
    console.log($rootScope.user);
    $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
    $rootScope.$apply();
});
```

The code never gets to the lines after debugger; In fact, the code never makes the `$http` request at all. For some reason it stops and doesn't continue with the callback...or promise...I'm a bit confused as to what the technical difference is. :)

That being said, I've tested the POST call with `$.ajax` and everything returns properly, so something is off with my Angular code.

And the code that actually fires the request and does work with `$.ajax`:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('xxx')
  .factory('rpcService', function ($http) {

    return {
      request: function (method, params, callback) {
        var service = method.split('.');

        params = params || {};
        params.method = service[1];

        $.ajax('/services/' + service[0] + '.sjs', {
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: params,
          success: function(data, status, xhr) {
              if (callback) {
                  callback(data);
              }
          }
        });
      }
    }      
  });
```

I'm just unsure why the XHR request isn't being made.

Comment: could you share completed code and set up a plunker please

Comment: Unfortunately I can't setup a plunker for this, but let me add some more code.

Answer (score 2):

The API call may get an error so the callback was never triggered. Try to add `error()` callback like this:

```
return $http("POST", '/services/' + service[0] + '.sjs', params)
    .error(function (response) {
        return 'blah';
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
```

You can try it on this demo. Your code actually looks good.

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ES9v/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but it just doesn't work. I'm not getting a response from my server at all! The request never goes out, therefore no error.

Comment: If you open the demo, you can see your code is actually ok. And the code you just added using $.ajax() is not angular's way.

Comment: How do you see that it's ok? I'm looking at the network tab and nothing is happening? Excuse my ignorance but isn't that problem? LOL

Comment: open the webdebugger by hitting f12 if you use chrome and click run button on the page header.

Comment: Yes, when you do that, do you see anything in the Network tab related to the request? I do not.

Comment: If the API is up, then you will. Obviously, the API is not reachable if tested in jsfiddle.